# Depedent Filtering

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, data-validation

Setting up a Product Order Form in excel for basic users

There is a comprehensive product master data sheet that includes product range, supplier, categories etc. This will be hidden from end user view, but will be used to generate data validation lists.

I have outlined a simple example of the category types in the link below

[Example Master Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptsgo.png)

On the Product Order Form sheet, I want to return the product and its price based on the ProductType and Season filters selected by the user

For example: the user will select Fruit from the ProductType dropdown, then I would like to use a dependent dropdown list in the next column (Season) to show only the relevant season selections based on their first choice.

I know this could be done using a dependent list, I have been able to do this

My question is, since the data in the Season column has comma separated values if more than one season is applicable - is there a way to make the dependent filter display just the relevant values in a list - without the comma separation (below example, Fruit is selected as ProductType - how can I make the Season filter look as pictured, only the relevant seasons in a list, referencing the master data sheet as source data not another list)

[Example of goal drop down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnUkG.png)

Please note, the real data is far more complex with many more variable values, above is a simple example.

I am not looking at someone to do the work for me, I am just hoping someone has a suggestion to point me in the right direction and hopefully I can create a solution for the client with the data in its current format. I have spent hours trying to research a solution put as yet can’t find anything to point me in the right direction.

I know I can use a formula to convert comma separated values into a list of unique values in another column, and then use that list to generate the dependent data validation list

```
=UNIQUE(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,Sheet1!B:B),",","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s"))
```

Or more simply by using text to columns, comma delimiter etc and then remove duplicates. But I want to avoid having an actual list if possible as I don’t want the client to be updating lists as new products/categories are added.

I want to generate the unique list using the raw data (with comma separated variable fields) within the data validation input screen, and ensure that is dynamic and updates as the raw data is updated.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: Tetsujin, question has been edited with image examples included

Comment: @Toby,, you have committed one basic mistake & that is your fruit category has duplicates like one fruit has 3 seasons for Bananna & other has 1 for Lime. Since fruit is the key factor for data filter in this case any applied method will not deliver correct result,, so [edit] you post & data set as well,,, and share with us if any method U have tried so far,,, avoid votes to CLOSE the post !!

Comment: @Toby,, one immediate method I would like to suggest is the formula to pull comma separated values in Row and use those with DD list !!

Comment: @RajeshS , this is not a mistake. This is how the data I am working with comes from the client – one ProductType will have multiple Categories, within those categories there are multiple products. As I mentioned, the actual data is much more complicated, and for the real data the “Season” field holds up to 50 different options all comma separated and variable. The data is this way because the segments are changing, and at any time more ‘seasons’ can be added, and more products added to the list. See updated question for what I have considered and why it is not appropriate for this project

Comment: Toby - thank you, close vote retracted. Wish you luck.

Comment: @Toby ,,, season are never the concern the issue is that you have DUPLICATE in category check your SS,, FRUIT, and if this persists then any method will always read the 1st FRUIT found search will never reach to other FRUIT! In this situation you have to either suggest the client to rectify the category like FRUIT1, FRUIT2 or you need to take this opportunity,, hope U get my point !!